# Custom polygon by user in Map and Interactive marker in Flutter

Tags: flutter, polygon, collision-detection, interactive, fluttermap

I need to create game such as crop. User can create polygon (crop) in flutter_map. It is okay, I got it. But there is circle in center of map. I want when it above first marker of polygon, then something happens.  Like hitBox.
There photos from Google Earth

[image]

I want like that (below).

[image]